# Netcat command line issues

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, netcat

I am trying to collect statistics from a `memcached` server using `netcat`.

```
~ $nc 10.251.170.80 11211
stats
STAT pid 27508
STAT uptime 7940345
STAT time 1262949310
STAT version 1.2.4
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 1389.962693
STAT rusage_system 4857.247586
STAT curr_items 9154565
STAT total_items 615722800
STAT bytes 1994844049
STAT curr_connections 62
STAT total_connections 6263004
STAT connection_structures 148
STAT cmd_get 1925983531
STAT cmd_set 615722800
STAT get_hits 1334407705
STAT get_misses 591575826
STAT evictions 7125864
STAT bytes_read 454794886199
STAT bytes_written 176758890326
STAT limit_maxbytes 2147483648
STAT threads 4
END
```

I can't get my head around why

```
~ $echo stats | nc -vv 10.251.170.80 11211
Connection to 10.251.170.80 11211 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
~ $
```

just fails.

Is there a trick with nc not reading stdin properly ?

Something wrong with CR/LF ?

I've been trying every nc command-line options related to input (-C)

```
~ $echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
~ $bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.33(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The system is fedora 9.

Comment: Does the shell prompt return immediately or is there a delay? FYI it works as expected here.

Comment: There's not any reason it shouldn't work that I can think of. What version of nc? What happens if you try a request to another host?

Comment: -bash-3.2# rpm -qa | grep nc
   nc-1.84-10.fc6

   -bash-3.2# more /etc/redhat-release 
   CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

Comment: i thought it was fedora 9, but it is an old CentOS host that we use for monitoring ...

Comment: it seems related to netcat, because the same command run from my macbook works perfectly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on debian using both nc.openbsd and nc.traditional:

```
echo -e "stats\nquit" | nc 10.251.170.80  11211
```

your netcat appears to be closing the connection on EOF on stdin and not waiting for output..
you can try -q 1 or so..

> -q seconds   after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds  is  negative,  wait  forever.

Comment: i'm using netcat 1.84 which doesn't seem to provide this '-q' option. Will try we a more recent package. The "stats\nquit" doesn't make it either ...

Comment: echo "stats" | nc -i1 10.251.170.80 

did the trick. Thank you, the netcat that ships with fedora is NetBSD's, so that could explain the cmdline difference.

Comment: That -e flag was a huge help! Would be nice if the manpage had it documented.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a line like the following:

```
# (echo stats ; sleep 0.1) | netcat 10.251.170.80 11211
```

This seems to hold the connection open long enough to get the reply.

Answer (score 0):

No newline being sent?

What about trying:
    ~ $ echo -e 'stats\n' | nc -vv 10.251.170.80 11211

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue with [gearmand](http://gearman.org/). The only @d5ve sleep solution works for me:

```
(echo status; sleep 0.1) | nc -w1 locahost 4730
```